# Authorize.NET gateway API for Android is not working

Tags: android, authorize.net

I am trying Authorize.net payment API. I have done all the steps shown in this [tutorial page](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/).

But when I click on the `Login` button it is not doing anything, meaning It is not saying that my username/password is incorrect or correct, nothing.

As per the tutorial link the step 7 is not working properly.

When the app starts, click the "Authorize and Capture" button. You will be prompted with a dialog that asks you to enter in your Login ID and Password. These are your Authorize.Net account login credentials.

If this is the first time you are performing this login from a new device (either real or virtual), the login will fail and state that the device has been registered but is pending approval. In this case, you will need to login to the sandbox (https://test.authorize.net/) and enable the new device. You can find this by going to:

Home > Account (Settings) > Security Settings (Mobile Device Management)

Once there, you should see your new device in a 'Pending' state. Click on the new device and enable it. Click the Login button again; the transaction should succeed and you will be prompted with an authCode and refTransId.

My code of ExampleActivity is same as there in that link. I have given proper permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

Here is my logcat details,

```
02-18 16:43:05.454: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:05.954: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:06.454: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:06.954: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:07.454: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:07.954: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:08.454: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:08.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:09.459: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:09.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:10.459: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:10.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:11.459: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:11.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:12.459: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:12.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:13.459: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
02-18 16:43:13.959: D/AuthNetActivityBase(11420): sleeping getMerchant()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solve this problem my self,

I did a mistake in step 2 from the [tutorial page](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/). I have just reconfigured the application again and it is working fine.

Comment: When I run the sample it is working fine but integrate this sample into my app progress dialog is showing continously and locat showing the same log that u have posted above plzz help @user3322955

Comment: @NeetuShrivastava Have you got any sol for this, I have the same problem " integrate this sample into my app" not working.

Comment: as @user3322955 has mentioned step two, it means you need to add permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> in Manifiest file

Comment: @AndroGeek I know that, I added that and its working for me, while i am integrating this project to mine its showing the error.

Comment: You have posted the below code with solution. Just read the doc carefully and debug your code. I dnt remember rite now what i did for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found and solved the problem.

There is a class in Authorize.net sample called **MobileMerchantAuthActivity.java**, here is a AsyncTask **ExecuteTransactionTask**, which is called inside the login button click, like this.

```
validateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showLoggingInDialog();
                    Log.d("Mobile_merchent", "after dialog called  " + loginIdEdit.getText().toString() +"   "+
                            passwordEdit.getText().toString());

                    PasswordAuthentication passAuth = PasswordAuthentication
                        .createMerchantAuthentication(loginIdEdit.getText().toString(),
                            passwordEdit.getText().toString(), deviceId);
                    _merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(env, passAuth);
                    Log.d("Mobile_merchent", "before asynctask called  ");

                    new ExecuteTransactionTask().execute();

                    }
                });
```

After integrating this project with my project the `new ExecuteTransactionTask().execute();` never getting executed [I dont know what the reason is
:( ]. So I changed the AsyncTask as a normal **Thread** with a **runOnUiThread**() and its working fine now. My new code for replacing the AsyncTask is given below and its working fine.

```
protected void ExecuteTransactionTask_thread() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread_replace_asynctask = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    try {
                        Log.d("Mobile_merchent", "asynctask called  ");
                        net.authorize.mobile.Transaction transaction = _merchant
                            .createMobileTransaction(TransactionType.MOBILE_DEVICE_LOGIN);
                        MobileDevice mobileDevice = MobileDevice.createMobileDevice(deviceId,
                            deviceDescription, deviceTelephoneNumber);
                        transaction.setMobileDevice(mobileDevice);
                        result = (net.authorize.mobile.Result) _merchant
                            .postTransaction(transaction);

                        // if the device hasn't been registered, register now and go from there
                        if (result.isResponseError()
                            && (result.getMessages().size() == 1 && MessageType.E00054
                                .equals(result.getMessages().get(0)))) {
                            transaction = _merchant
                                .createMobileTransaction(TransactionType.MOBILE_DEVICE_REGISTRATION);
                            transaction.setMobileDevice(mobileDevice);
                            result = (net.authorize.mobile.Result) _merchant
                                .postTransaction(transaction);

                            // attempt login again
                            transaction = _merchant
                                .createMobileTransaction(TransactionType.MOBILE_DEVICE_LOGIN);
                            transaction.setMobileDevice(mobileDevice);
                            result = (net.authorize.mobile.Result) _merchant
                                .postTransaction(transaction);
                        }
                        resultCode = result.isResponseOk() ? RESULT_OK
                            : SimpleActivity.RESULT_FAILURE;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "executeTransaction failed.", e);
                        resultCode = SimpleActivity.RESULT_FAILURE;
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("Mobile_merchent", "asynctask post called  " + String.valueOf(resultCode));

                            switch (resultCode) {
                            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                                dismissLoggingInDialog();
                                finish();
                                break;
                            case SimpleActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
                                if (result != null) {
                                    showAlert(result.getMessages().size() > 0 ? result.getMessages()
                                        .get(0).getText() : MessageType.E00000.getText());
                                } else {
                                    setResult(SimpleActivity.RESULT_FAILURE);
                                    dismissLoggingInDialog();
                                    finish();
                                }
                                break;
                            case RESULT_OK:

                                // check if the result was from a registration or a successful login
                                AuthNetActivityBase.sessionToken = result.getSessionToken();
                                SessionTokenAuthentication sessionTokenAuthentication = SessionTokenAuthentication
                                    .createMerchantAuthentication(_merchant.getMerchantAuthentication()
                                        .getName(), result.getSessionToken(), deviceId);
                                _merchant.setMerchantAuthentication(sessionTokenAuthentication);

                                setResultIntent();
                                break;
                            }   
                        }
                    });



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread_replace_asynctask.start();
    }
```

And call `ExecuteTransactionTask_thread()` function in login button click instead of `new ExecuteTransactionTask().execute();`, It will work for sure.